# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'has')

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to check if the member is the owner of the server, but I am getting an error.
My code:

```js
const member = message.mentions.users.first();
        const reason = args.slice(1).join(' ') || 'No reason specified.'

        
        if (member.permissions.has('MANAGE_GUILD')) return message.reply( 'I cannot moderate the owner of the server.')
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'has')
```

I am using discord.js v13 and Node.js 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) doesn't have a `permissions` property.

However, [a `GuildMember` has](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=permissions).

The solution is therefore not to access the first `User` in the mentions as you do now (into a variable confusingly called `member`) but the first `GuildMember`, using the [`members` property of the `MessageMentions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=members):

```js
const member = message.mentions.members.first();
//                              ^^^^^^^
```